# Deserializing LangChain messages

Tags: serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization, langchain, langchain-js

LangChain's [`BaseMessage`](https://api.js.langchain.com/classes/schema.BaseMessage.html) has a function [`toJSON`](https://api.js.langchain.com/classes/schema.BaseMessage.html#toJSON) that returns a [`Serialized`](https://api.js.langchain.com/types/load_serializable.Serialized.html).

Once I have a list of `BaseMessage`s, I can use `toJSON` to serialize them, but how can I later deserialize them?

```js
const messages = [
  new HumanMessage("hello"),
  new AIMessage("foo"),
  new HumanMessage("bar"),
  new AIMessage("baz"),
];

const serialized = messages.map((message) => message.toJSON());

const deserialized = ???
```

Comment: Have you found the solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up rolling my own (de)serialization.